# Insert codesnippet into app or web config c# visual studio 2010 -2013

Tags: c#

Wondering if is possible to create a xml snippet and then when you are in the app config or web config type the shortcut for your snippet and appears in the app.config.

I tried but does not work.

Is it possible? 
thanks

Comment: at work I work from vs2005 to vs2013 as we have many applications that will not be upgraded.Do you have a link or how do you do it

Comment: It works for me in VS2010.

Comment: what did you do?May be I am missing the obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

I have created the following snippet:

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>
      Element</Title>
    <Author>just me</Author>
    <Shortcut>blah</Shortcut>
    <Description>
     test</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>name</ID>
        <ToolTip>
          Parent element name.</ToolTip>
        <Default>element</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="XML"><![CDATA[blah!]]></Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

and saved it in 
`...Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets\XML\My Xml Snippets\config.snippet`

When I'm in the `app.config` I can either right-click > Insert Snippet or hit `Ctrl+K,X` to select the `Blah` snippet and `blah!` gets inserted.

Comment: The right-click > Insert Snippet and Ctrl + K,X was what helped me.  I was not able to get this to show up with intellisense or Ctrl + J.